# How to print image using javascript:window.print()

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript code to print my webpage. Then I found this one - javascript:window.print() and I used it as:

```
<span class = "printIt"><a href = "javascript:window.print()">PRINT</a></span>
```

It is functional. However, I found out that this code can't print the image displayed in my webpage. Only the html and css are printable.
When I tried to use the usual way of printing and press ctrl+p both image and style (CSS) are not printable.

May you please tell me what's the problem with this?

thank you!

Comment: browser setting perhaps? which browser

Comment: I've tried it with IE 11, firefox and google chrome. But the output is still the same

Comment: Show the HTML and the CSS of the image. Is it a background image? By default browsers don't print background images.

Comment: yes it is,
I set the CSS like this:

#Image
{
 width:1100px;
 height:160px;
/* margin-left:6px;*/
 margin-top:10px;
 background:url(../img/IwantToBeAMember/boracay_beach.jpg) no-repeat;
 border-radius:10px;
}